# Cask 'dbeaver-community' definition is invalid: invalid 'sha256' value

Tags: macos, homebrew

when I using this command in macOS 12.5 to upgrade the DBeaver:

```
➜  ~ brew install --cask dbeaver-community
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services, skipping update!
Running `brew update --auto-update`...


==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 4 taps (homebrew/cask, dart-lang/dart, datawire/blackbird and sass/sass).
==> New Casks
bookwright        cider             filen             glance-chamburr   httpie            mints             texifier          trunk-io
chromium-gost     decentr           fresh             goxel             micromamba        qspace-pro        tl-legacy
Warning: Unexpected method 'arch' called on Cask another-redis-desktop-manager.
Follow the instructions here:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
Error: Cask 'another-redis-desktop-manager' definition is invalid: invalid 'sha256' value: {:arm=>"d0db344005bcfec3dfea7c5e38fd8dbdcfceb53481b6d73bfc82a56f6918cc0f", :intel=>"06bdff9503baef0abc095d4fae119f47ae852673326ec8217ace75a2278703e3"}
Warning: Unexpected method 'arch' called on Cask dbeaver-community.
Follow the instructions here:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
Error: Cask 'dbeaver-community' definition is invalid: invalid 'sha256' value: {:arm=>"ec2f141678c659b1616af38d345642f1619e5e42272969ab9cbdcca9bba790fa", :intel=>"81d2f1cbbe40d6bc6ad1f8b442a3f1d384a77a06cf3d694153679d32d6b9f8f2"}
```

what should I do to fixed this problem?

Comment: Did you run `brew doctor` and fix whatever needs fixing?

Comment: This is what happens when you use cask.  The real developer has updated their download, and the shasum no longer matches what Homebrew has recorded.  You are at the mercy of Homebrew to update their formula.